# Call of Duty Ghosts Private Hardcore Match with Killcam enabled

Tags: call-of-duty-ghosts

Is it possible to host a private hardcore match and have killcam enabled?
It's way more fun that way.

Thanks.

Comment: Please don't edit the question for no reason. It can be phrased in many ways, but unless it's intelligible or somehow breaking rules, don't. You'll say "thanks" at the end is not OK. I don't agree, but go ahead and remove that - just that.

Comment: Read comment, don't edit without reason. KTHXBAI

Comment: According to [This](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6950/when-should-we-edit-game-names-out-of-question-titles-and-why) and [This](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4973/is-it-appropriate-to-remove-thanks-from-posts) Meta posts, we remove both Game Names from Titles, and 'Thanks' from question bodies. This is why your question has been edited twice.

Comment: Removing game name from the title seems odd, especially for posts such as this one. The "thanks" removal I mentioned in my first comment. Go ahead and remove that if it "makes the platform better" because clearly that's the problem with SO.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation though, don't get me wrong.

Comment: Send me the link to your trickshot montage after you get your answer ;)

Comment: What do you mean, Rainbows? :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes but you have to work around the fact that you cannot change the hardcore preset settings. In order to be *somewhat* hardcore, but have a killcam change the private match settings to:

**Player Options**

- Max Health: Minuscule
- Health Regeneration : None

**Team Options**

- KillCam: Enabled
- Radar Always On: No
- Friendly Fire: Enabled

**Gameplay Options**

- Hardcore Mode: **Disabled**

Note: The HUD is still on while playing. There is no setting to enable/disable it. Also if you Enable Hardcore mode the HUD will be hidden but the option to enable/disable KillCams will be locked.

Comment: I'm doing that already, but the HUD is still visible. In the past, this could be overridden for Harcore - the killcam I mean. It now has a lock to its right, which makes me think it's possible to unlock.

Comment: Well there is no other options.... The only way to unlock the lock is by disabling hardcore...